# How to click in a place on chrome opened window with exaxt coordination in selenium python?

Tags: click, coordinates, action, offset, exacttarget

I want to click in exactly pointed place in the image below.
I tried this methods:

actions.move_by_offset(element, 91, 114).click().perform()

actions.move_to_element_with_offset(element,91 ,114).click().perform()

Also I tried by pyautogui library but I didn't get success.

Comment: Which Image and website?